# Running Gradle Causes - Error: Could not find or load main class security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: java, gradle, bouncycastle

So I was messing around setting up bouncy castle with my JRE, editing the file 'java.security'. Now when I run the gradle command, I receive:

```
C:\temp>gradle
Error: Could not find or load main class security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I've completely uninstalled/deleted my JDK,JRE,Gradle user home, & Gradle installations / directories. I've installed newer versions of the JDK & JRE, same version of Gradle, but in a different directory. But I still get:

```
C:\temp>gradle
Error: Could not find or load main class security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Why???

Comment: Do you have a `build.gradle` on `C:\temp` where you're running `gradle`? Or you are simply trying `gradle` command on a empty directory?

Comment: I've done both to no avail - same message about the security provider

Comment: This may have some bearing on the issue you're seeing: http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/BUG-BC-ver-jdk15on-151-RegressionTest-Exceptions-CipherStreamTest-CertPathValidator-CertPathBuilder-td4657477.html

Comment: No dice - I've completely deleted the jdk, jre, and gradle directories, installed new versions of the jdk & jre in different directories, as well as given all directories (including gradle) different names.

Something is being retained...somewhere. I'm not sure where yet. Registry? Home directory hidden file? Environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it. I had done:

```
JAVA_OPTS=security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Removed that, and all good now.

Comment: As an environment variable?

Comment: Is not a good idea set up an alternative provider at the highest preference, the highest preference should be always for **sun.security.provider.Sun** because  there are occasionally internal dependencies on the provider at first position which may cause some operations by your JVM to result in errors.